# how to manage build and deployments from Multi repos using versions

Tags: git, repository, dependencies, dependency-management

Consider you have two repos `A`, `B`.
Let say repo `A` has some infrastructure code - not needed to be updated always-
but it has the code for the service we want to deploy as infra.

On the other hand, repo `B` include all business logic to be run inside of the wrapper service mentioned in repo `A`.
So dependency is that `A` repo is using repo `B`, not vice versa.

How would you handle versioning of each repo, and in deploy context especially?

I guess we should have some changelog\tags for denoting versions **for each** repo `A` - infra code wrappings and `B` for common business logic to be launched from wrapper service.

How would a deploy service would look like, triggered from what?
I thought of triggering it from new tag on repo `A` - which can denote code change in infra code.

But, probably most of the time we will have more code changes from repo `B` , so maybe by having tag trigger on this repo also?

Or maybe more reasonable to have some configuration file in repo `A` for denoting which repo `B` version we should use while assembling repos to one docker image?

I would like to hear about similar use cases and how it was handled to get more ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have your dependency the wrong way around. By having your stable repository A depend on your volatile repository B, you will need to make changes to and releases from A just to update the link to B.

Another reason is because a dependency relation between two components does not always match the direction that function calls are made in, especially if one of the components is some kind of framework. Suppose next month or next year a new application needs to be built that also runs inside the wrapper service from repo A, but is completely independent (also in release cycles) from the application in repo B. You wouldn't want to have a link from A to both B and C, because that would make it impossible to build/release B independent of C and vice versa.

Actually, A should be regarded as a framework, with B depending on A even though the actual function calls are made from A code to B code.

That also solves your versioning problem.

- You create releases of A when the framework code changes
- B depends on a particular release of A
- You create releases from B when the business logic changes
- The deploy service would take the code from a tagged version from B, then the corresponding linked version from A and deploy the combination.

Comment: Thank you very much for you explanations.
Repo `A` is framework design to be just for this purpose, it won't populate other Frameworks parallel to it- it was taken into consideration.


"Actually, A should be regarded as a framework, with B depending on A even though the actual function calls are made from A code to B code."
It's exactly my state- correct me if I'm wrong. `B` is common Business logic, A is Framework which wrapping some of the components from common taht are needed.

Comment: I don't think that "B depends on a particular release of A" is good idea given the fact the repo `B` is already being used by other repos as Business logic also. So it can have such config used by some of repos- but I like to generilize and not being specific

Comment: "The deploy service would take the code from a tagged version from B, then the corresponding linked version from A and deploy the combination." 
=> Sounds nice idea also, but require to store tag version for repo `A` in `B` repo, which is not so clean maybe

Comment: @Mulder, what you describe here in the comments paints a completely different picture than what you described in the question. Can you update your question to better reflect the repositories you have and how they are used? Perhaps also use more meaningful names to refer to those repositories.